# How can we get azure sql database metrics report in excel (cpu percentage,dtu percentage,deadlocks,failed connection) using powershell of last 7 days

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, metrics

I have to generate a database report on last 7 days of performance that include cpu percentage,dtu percentage,deadlocks,failed connections Using powershell of all azure subscription.please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please google your problem and come up with some basic Powershell code, and explain the issue you have with it

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure Portal, where you have chart data, is one approach to rapidly search and query metrics data. However, you may choose to obtain the raw data and query it yourself. Below is a Powershell sample for obtaining this info.

In this other page, you may find the other potential metric names to pass in as parameters - Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftsqlserversdatabases).

```
$MonitorParameters = @{
ResourceId = "/subscriptions/$($SubscriptionID)/resourceGroups/$($ResourceGroup)/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$($ServerName)/databases/$($DBName)"
TimeGrain = $TimeGrain
MetricNames = $MetricName
StartTime = (Get-Date).AddDays($DaysToLook)
}
$Metrics = Get-AzMetric @MonitorParameters -DetailedOutput
```

TimeStamp           Average Metric

---

07/10/2020 11:07:00       0 dtu_consumption_percent
07/10/2020 11:07:00      10 dtu_limit
07/10/2020 11:07:00       0 dtu_used
07/10/2020 11:12:00       0 dtu_consumption_percent
07/10/2020 11:12:00      10 dtu_limit
07/10/2020 11:12:00       0 dtu_used
07/10/2020 11:17:00    19,6 dtu_consumption_percent

```
$metric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<group-name>/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/<cloudservice-name>/slots/production/roles/WebRole1" -TimeGrain 00:15:00 -MetricName "Percentage CPU"
$metric.Data
```

Use PowerShell to monitor and scale a single database in Azure SQL Database | [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/scripts/monitor-and-scale-database-powershell).